# Construct a sequence using the fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, recurrence-relations

Consider the Fourier transform defined as

$$
\mathcal{F}[f](p) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)e^{-j2\pi xp}dx
$$

Assume that

$$
f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1 & |x| < \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

under such hypothesis we now that

$$
\mathcal{F}[f](p) = \hat{f}(p)= \frac{\sin(\pi p)}{\pi p} = \text{sinc(p)}
$$

I'm trying to build a sequence whose convergence will be studied later, for now I'm just interested in the construction. Let

$$
p_{k+1} = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
p_0 & k = -1 \\
p_{k} + \delta_{k} & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

where $\delta_k$ is a convergent sequence, this should imply that $p_k$ converges as well. So for all $k$ we have fixed $\delta_k$. Say I'd like to evaluate $\hat{f}$ at $p_{k+1}$ then I'd have

$$
\hat{f}(p_{k+1}) = \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-j2\pi xp_{k+1}}dx = \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-j2\pi xp_k}e^{-j2\pi x\delta_k}dx
$$

Is there any manipulation that maybe I'm missing that would allow to express the last integral in a useful form? It does resemble a bit the fourier series, if $\delta_k$ would be $k$ (though it wouldn't make the sequence converge) that would be a fourier coefficient. But I'm sure there's something there that can be useful.

I'm mostly looking for a recursive expression.

Comment: There is no question here. And $p_k$ converges iff $\sum_k \delta_k$ converges

Comment: Of course... what do you mean there's no construction?

Comment: There is no mathematical question here.

Comment: @user1952009 I quote myself "Is there any manipulation that maybe I'm missing that would allow to express the last integral in a useful form?" Isn't that a mathematical question?

Comment: no. useful for what ?

Comment: @user1952009 I quote myself "I'm mostly looking for a recursive expression". Basically something like
$$
f(p_{k+1}) = g(f(p_{k}),\delta_k)
$$

Comment: Why ? What do you want to do ?

Comment: Transforming the problem of computing sinc function (which is hard) into a sequence of simpler problem to solve.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. Computing $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not hard

Comment: That depends from the point of view... And I still don't understand what is unclear in my question.